# Trying to get a C++ program to loop back to another point in the code

Tags: c++, loops

I have recently started learning C++ and have come stuck during trying to make a program. I am trying to get the program to link back to the starting options if they enter something which wasn't an option using a while loop. I found a way of doing it using purely if/else statements but it was horrifically inefficient and terrible. Here is my current code:

```
// program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    option:
    int option = 0;
  std::cout << "Workout App \n\n";
  std::cout << "Please enter which function you wish to engage from the following list: \n ";
  std::cout << "Press 1 for a BMI calculation \n " ;
  std::cout << "Press 2 for a bodyweight circuit builder \n " ;
  std::cout << "Press 3 for a weekly workout program, based upon fitness level and goals \n ";
  std::cout << "Press 4 for to do the roar \n ";
  std::cin >> option;

  while (true){


      if (option==1){
          std::cout << "BMI Calculation engaged... \n\n";
          //Run a seperate section of the program, that loops back to the options afterward and has an option to quit the program, for now its contained here.
          double height, weight, bmi;

          std::cout << "Type in your height (m): ";
          std::cin >> height;

          std::cout << "Type in your weight (kg): ";
          std::cin >> weight;

          bmi = weight / (height * height);

          std::cout << "Your BMI is " << bmi << "\n";

          return 0;
          break;
      }

      else if (option==2){
          std::cout << "BW Circuit Builder engaged... \n\n";
          //Run a seperate section of the program, that loops back to the options afterward and has an option to quit the program
          break;
      }

      else if (option==3){
          std::cout << "Weekly Workout Program engaged... \n\n";
          //Run a seperate section of the program, that loops back to the options afterward and has an option to quit the program
          break;
      }

      else if (option==4){
          std::cout << "I love you, Daddy. \n";
          break;
      }

      else {
          std::cout << "Try again \n";
          std::cin >> option;
        //Get this section to loop back to the starting options

      }
  }




 }
```

I have tried using the goto function, however this did not work either. Is anyone able to help me here?
Thanks

Comment: Place the whole program (minus the title section) in a `while(true)` loop, instead of just the "decision-making" portion :)

Comment: Why don't you put your menu/options stuff in a function that you can then call whenever needed?

Comment: alteredinstance, i tried this but nothing sems to have changed?

Comment: Jesper, how would I do that?

Comment: *I have tried using the goto function, however this did not work either.* It rarely does. And when it does, good luck convincing your co-workers of that.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::cin >> option;

while (true) { ... }
```

will read the input once, then loop endlessly. What you want is to read the read the input in each loop:

```
while (true) { 
    std::cin >> option;
    ... 
}
```

You could also put the first part of your program (where you print the menu) inside this loop, to print the menu in each loop.

But then you should remove the `std::cin >> option;` option in the last else.

Comment: Note that it might be helpful to display the menu again inside the loop. But that is optional.